# Is there better syntax for simple if, assigning variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, if-statement

I have code that basically assigns a variable in one case, else a different in another. Is there a neater way that is more efficient?

I.e., not taking up so many lines. Or is this the best way?

```
 if (ViewBag.Date != RoomBooking.StartDateTime.Date || ViewBag.DayPlannerStartTime * 12 > (Int32)RoomBooking.StartDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 5)
        {
            StartBlock = ViewBag.DayPlannerStartTime * 12;
        }
        else
        {
            StartBlock = ((Int32)RoomBooking.StartDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 5);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think that there is. Any change will require the use of conditional statement `x?y:z` which is less readable. Readability accounts for a lot in code maintenance and in anycase the executable wouldn't be any more efficient than what you have now.

Comment: Yea, changing it across its harder to see where my ifs are. Ill try refactoring my code to require so many in the first place or something. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this (it's arguably neater, but definitely has the same efficiency):

```
StartBlock = (ViewBag.Date != RoomBooking.StartDateTime.Date || ViewBag.DayPlannerStartTime * 12 > (Int32)RoomBooking.StartDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 5)
    ? ViewBag.DayPlannerStartTime * 12
    : ((Int32)RoomBooking.StartDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 5);
```

**EDIT:** You can slightly optimize the condition as well. I suspect that your `DayPlannerStartTime` is expressed in seconds, and if I'm right you can rewrite the comparison the following way (I just divided both operands of the `>` operator by 12, and `TotalMinutes` divided by 5*12 became `TotalHours`):

```
ViewBag.DayPlannerStartTime > (Int32)RoomBooking.StartDateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I thought id come across it at some point. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Doomsknight: yes, this was my fault, sorry. The right side divided by 12 converts minutes into hours, of course. But anyway, you got the idea.

Comment: Yea, I've improved it, thanks :) (removed my comment because I was so confused whether I was wrong :p)

Comment: @Doomsknight: Thank you for pointing my mistake out, I updated my answer so it won't confuse anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to create a single expression that will evaluate to the first expression if the condition is true, or else to the second expression:

```
// condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
var value = (something that is true or false) ? value if true : value if false;
```